# git-svn: How to know current SVN revision of a git-svn working copy?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a git-svn working copy and git log gives me no direct info about which SVN revision I'm on. I understand that once I rebase I should have all upstream logs converted into git log, but that still doesn't seem to give a REVISION NUMBER to me and I'd have to do text mining to find out.

Is there a simple command that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows up at the bottom of each commit message. There's a log line similar to this:

```
git-svn-id: http://svn.example.com/trunk/whatever@12345 [git-svn remote hash]
```

The `12345` is that commit's SVN revision